# Pyspark Json Struct

Tags: json, pyspark, struct

I am trying to create 1 json from a DF which has 3 entries for 1 Customer,

```
+----------+---------------+---------+-----------------+-----------+---------------+---------+-----------------+--------------------+------------------+------+
|CustomerId|EmailPreference|EmailType|AddressPreference|AddressType|PhonePreference|PhoneType|        attribute|                from|                to|action|
+----------+---------------+---------+-----------------+-----------+---------------+---------+-----------------+--------------------+------------------+------+
|C1000001|        Primary|     Home|             null|       null|           null|     null|     EmailAddress|TEST@Solutions.com|WELL@Solutions.com|UPDATE|
|C1000001|           null|     null|             null|       null|        Primary|     Home|      PhoneNumber|          8177777777|        8168888888|UPDATE|
|C1000001|           null|     null|             null|       null|        Primary|     Home|FormatPhoneNumber|       (816)777-7777|     (816)888-8888|UPDATE|
+----------+---------------+---------+-----------------+-----------+---------------+---------+-----------------+--------------------+------------------+------+
```

This is our updatesDF. So I am trying to create a struct out of this in such a way that we need 1 json entry for 1 Customer. So here for 1 customer, there were 3 updates. So this is what I had tried,

```
json_df = updatesDF.select(
      F.col("CustomerId").alias("CustomerId"),
   #   "action",
      "PhonePreference",
      "EmailPreference",
      
      F.struct(
        F.col("PhoneType"),
        F.col("PhonePreference"),
        F.col("Attribute"),
        F.col("From"),
        F.col("To"),
      ).alias("PhoneDetails"),

      F.struct(
        F.col("EmailType"),
        F.col("EmailPreference"),  
        F.col("Attribute"),
        F.col("From"),
        F.col("To"),
        ).alias("EmailDetails"),
    ).groupBy(
    "CustomerId",
      "PhonePreference",
    "EmailPreference",
    ).agg(
    F.collect_list("PhoneDetails").alias("PhoneDetails"),
    F.collect_list("EmailDetails").alias("EmailDetails"),)
```

So the problem with this code is, I am getting 2 jsons as output, I need one output for 1 Customer

Could you please help so that finally I get just 1 json with all email changes under emaildetails and all phone changes under phonedetails

Comment: Can you add the code for creating your sample dataframe please?

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You get 2 rows since your `groupBy` has two unique combinations.

- `(C1000001, null, Primary)`
- `(C1000001, Primary, null)`

One workaround is that you only `groupBy` `CustomerId` and in the aggregation apply `first("EmailPreference", ignorenulls=True)` and `first("PhonePreference", ignorenulls=True)`

Answer (score 0):

You're half-way through it, all you have to do is groupby one more time with only `CustomerID` and add both `PhoneDetails` and `EmailDetails` into one other struct

```
    .select(
        'CustomerId',
        F.struct(
            F.col('PhoneDetails'),
            F.col('EmailDetails')
        ).alias('updates')
    )
    .groupBy('CustomerId')
    .agg(F.collect_list('updates').alias('updates'))
```